# How to set size for launch screen icon?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to setup a launch screen that will flow seamlessly into a personal splash screen in flutter.

The goal is that I have the logo, centered on both Launch and Splash, that is lets say 10px from both left and right of a portrait only app.

I don't understand what image size I would need to be able to set this up properly on Android. I have drawable-**** folders with varied sizes but they don't fit correctly. Other than 'centering' the image in the Android xml I don't know how I would make it 'fit width' basically.

On iOS my icons show up as centered in the LaunchScreen.storyboard but are super tiny (96x96). If I manually resize the image to fit the way I want(in Xcode view scene), when I run the app I get a warning saying that the view does not have unlatching constraints and it will be shown as the original small size.

Answer (score 0):

launch screen icon use fit function

for example

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
    // in the middle of the parent.
    child: Image.asset('repo/intro.jpg' width: 100 , height: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

apple launch Storyboard use fit too